# Recursive function with defer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, deferred, angular-promise

I want to use a recursive function but each function should run after previuse complete.
so I write this code:

```
var service = ['users', 'news'],
    lastSync = {
                 'users' : false,
                 'news' : false
               };
db.transaction(function (tx) {
   lastSyncFunc(tx,service,0).then(function(){
       console.log(lastSync);
   });
});

function lastSyncFunc(tx,service,index){
   deferred = $q.defer();
   tx.executeSql("SELECT time FROM last_sync WHERE fService = ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1", [service[index]], function (tx, result) {
       if (result.rows.length > 0) {
           lastSync[service[index]] = result.rows.item(0).fTime;
       }
       return ++index<service.length ? lastSyncFunc(tx,service,index) : deferred.resolve();
   });
   return deferred.promise;
}
```

now my program return `false` for `lastSync.users` and `lastSync.users` because run this section before function completely run.

Comment: You cannot `return` from the `executeSql` callback. Properly abstract over callbacks and use promises, before going into application-specific procedures like that recursive call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Manual multiple async calls handling is not always best decision.

You can try to use `$q.all()` for that.*

To be simple, second step should be write promisified version for single query:

```
const pDbExec = (tx, sql, params = []) => {
  let deferred = $q.defer();
  tx.executeSql(sql, params, (tx, res) => deferred.resolve(res));
  return deferred.promise();
}
```

*First step should be "check of existance of promisified version of library/methods I use".*

Then, just call `$q.all` with map your service list into promises:

```
const SQL_SvcLastSync = `SELECT time FROM ... LIMIT 1`;
db.transaction(tx => {
  $q.all(service.map(svc => pDbExec(tx, SQL_SvcLastSync, [svc])))
    .then(results => 
       results.map(res => 
         res.rows.length > 0 ? res.rows.item(0).fTime : null))
    .then(results => console.log(results));
});
```

To format results as key/value pairs you have two options:

- Add reducer: 
  `.then(results => 
    results.reduce((acc, res, i) => (acc[service[i]]=res, acc), {}))`
- provide key/value(where values are promises) instead of array map to $q.all, so they will be resolved under same keys.
  You'll need to modify intermediate mapper, sure.

---

Simple solution with adding parameter for saving same deferred object between recursive calls:

try something like this:

```
function lastSyncFunc(tx,service,index, def){
   var deferred = def || $q.defer();
   tx.executeSql(
     "SELECT time FROM last_sync WHERE fService = ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1", 
     [service[index]], 
     function (tx, result) {
       if (result.rows.length > 0) {
           lastSync[service[index]] = result.rows.item(0).fTime;
       }
       return ++index<service.length ? 
         lastSyncFunc(tx,service,index, deferred) : 
         deferred.resolve();
   });
   return deferred.promise;
}
```

I just a provide deferred to maxdepth, where we can to resolve it.

Comment: I never worked with deferred, may be this solution is not `best pratices` ;)

Answer (score 1):

The *de facto* way to do this is to avoid recursion as described [here](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/) under the heading "The Collection Kerfuffle".

The advocated pattern can be coded with everything inside a `db.transaction(function() {...})` structure but it's clearer to pull `tx.executeSql(...)` out and promisify it in a separate function.

You will end up with something like this :

```
var service = ['users', 'news'],
    lastSync = {
        'users' : false,
        'news' : false
    };
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    return service.reduce(function(promise, serviceItem) {
        return promise.then(function() {
            return executeSqlPromisified(tx, serviceItem).then(function(fTime) {
                if(fTime !== null) {
                    lastSync[serviceItem] = fTime;
                }
            });
        });
    }, $q.when(null)).then(function() {
        console.log(lastSync);
    });
});

function executeSqlPromisified(tx, serviceItem) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    tx.executeSql("SELECT time FROM last_sync WHERE fService = ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1", [serviceItem], function (tx, result) {
        if (result.rows.length) {
            deferred.resolve(result.rows.item(0).fTime);
        } else {
            deferred.resolve(null);
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

To the untrained eye, this will be pretty well unreadable but trust me, you can get used to this pattern.

Comment: Thanks for answer, what is `serviceItem` ? because we don't have `serviceItem` in our variables. and how the `service` will increment ?

Comment: When I run this code I get error, error is : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined ` on line `return promise.then(function() {`

Comment: `serviceItem` is just an element of the `service` array, ie what is referred to as `service[index]` in the code in the question, ie 'users' then 'news'.  `service` is iterated by the `service.reduce(...)` construction. `.reduce()` is a standard javascript array method.

Comment: The error you are seeing is probably caused by `$q.defer().resolve()`, which is my attempt at creating a resolved $q promise. Maybe `$q.defer().resolve(null).promise` will work. It's far simpler with a full implementation of `Q` but $q leaves out a lot of features (and I am less familiar with it).

Comment: Thanks for explanation, so is your mean I cannot use `promise` in AngularJS `$q` ? but I think the problem related to `promise` because in `return service.reduce(function(promise, serviceItem) {` we pass `promise` argument but this argument not define before. isn't it ?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that. I'm just making a poor apology for having made a mistake in my answer.

Comment: `.reduce()` is confusing if you are not familiar with it. Its callback function is called by internal javascript code which passes two parameters to it. I have chosen to name the corresponding arguments `promise` and `serviceItem`. In javascript documentation, they are typically named `prev` (previous) and `current` but I have used names appropriate to this particular usage.

Comment: I found the problem, I read about `.reduce()` in https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce , first value (`promise`) is `previousValue` so for first time when program will run the `promise` is empty. what should I do for the first time?

Comment: That's why `.resolve()` takes a second parameter, `$q.defer().resolve(null).promise` in this case. I have made that edit in the answer.

Comment: The pattern is easier to understand in [the reference I gave earlier](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/) - search the page for "arr.reduce".

Comment: Thanks, but with this change my application not work yet :( , now I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'promise' of undefined` on line `}, $q.defer().resolve(null).promise).then(function() {`

Comment: Thanks, now error changed to: `Error: Failed to execute 'executeSql' on 'SQLTransaction': SQL execution is disallowed.`

Comment: If you want to get it working, then you will have to debug it. I'm working blind here with no means to debug. If that's too much trouble, then I will delete my answer. After all, you already have something that works from the other answer..